# CRON_TZ and Ubuntu: how to setup per-task timezones?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu version of cron doesn't support timezones with `CRON_TZ`.

Part of cron jobs should be run up in local timezone (and it's different on servers).

What alternative to default cron service can I use for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have `systemd` in place, I think that would be the most obvious option.

You can start units with [timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html), which can be scheduled with `OnCalendar` which has a lot of flexibility, including expressions such as [`Mon *-*-* 00:00:00 Pacific/Auckland`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html).

Comment: I thought about this solution, but the problem is I have to create a service for each job instead of adding a simple line to cron.

Comment: @DmitryR it's not clear why that's a problem. In fact, it sounds easier to manage.